# How to get rid of remaining orange lines when bridging?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I've bridged two edges together but there remains on orange line between them. I've checked for duplicates but haven't found any. Does anybody know why this is happening? I've picked up Blender again recently. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have a floating edge or overlapping vertices, maybe share your file so that we can check?

Comment: Here it is: https://we.tl/t-vhoQOuIenh

Comment: I solved it, I had to flip the normals.